# Null pointer exception when trying to set menu item icon in loader

Tags: android

I have a loader set up in which I try to set an icon of an item in the action bar in the onLoadFinished() method however I get a null pointer exception when trying to do so.

I am able to change the icon if I don't attempt to do it in the onLoadFinished() method however.

```
ActionMenuItemView actionBarMenuItem = (ActionMenuItemView) findViewById(R.id.action_item);
actionBarMenuItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_my_icon));

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.setIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
```

Has anyone come across this issue before or would be able to know why its occuring?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `findViewById()` on menu items in onCreate because the menu layout isn't inflated. You could create a global Menu variable and initialize it in the onCreateOptionsMenu() and then use it in your `onLoadFinished()`.

```
private Menu menu;
```

In your onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
this.menu = menu;
```

In your onLoadFinished() method

```
menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

Comment: you could start the loader from the onCreateOptionMenu function

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was driving me mad. In short, there is no guarantee (depending on API-version) that the menu (and its items) will be loaded by OnCreate and that is why you get the NPE.

I solved it by placing all logic for changes in the menu inside the onCreateOptionsMenu section. E.g.:

```
if (clientcount >=2)
{
    menuOnline.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.online));
}
else {
    menuOnline.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.offline));
}
```

After I setting *clientcount* i invoke invalidateOptionsMenu thus ensuring that the menu is loaded properly. 
That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed it this way. Maybe it's crooked, but it seems to work:

```
 public void syncStatus(final String input){
    if (mMenu == null){
        //wait 1 sec
        new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                //retry method
                syncStatus(input);
            }

        }.start();
        return;
    }
    mMenu.getItem(0).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.sync_off));
    }
```